# Reacts JS stops running

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser

I have the code below

```js
const secondsToString = (seconds) => {
  seconds = parseInt(seconds)
  let numdays = Math.floor(seconds / 86400);
  let numhours = Math.floor((seconds % 86400) / 3600);
  let numminutes = Math.floor(((seconds % 86400) % 3600) / 60);
  let numseconds = ((seconds % 86400) % 3600) % 60;
  if (numdays !== 0) {
    return numdays + "d " + numhours + "h " + numminutes + "m " + numseconds + "s";
  } else if (numhours !== 0) {
    return numhours + "h " + numminutes + "m " + numseconds + "s";
  } else if (numminutes !== 0){
    return numminutes + "m " + numseconds + "s";
  } else {
    return numseconds + "s";
  }
}

//more functions
const difference = (start) => {
  const startAt = Date.parse(start);
  const now   = Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = parseInt((now - startAt)/1000);
  return secondsToString(seconds)
};
//more functions





// in render
<td onClick={() => modalToggle()}>{difference(item.startsAt)}</td>
```

}

normally when I access this page the the td keeps updating and time keeps growing, but today sometimes it will for 30 seconds, and then it stops, sometimes it only runs once then stops.

It appears all javascript on the page stops.

I have websocket listeners, but new data doesn't appear unless I refresh or click on something.

What's strange is there were no changes to this and it stopped. The api appears to be fine as well,the logs don't show anything dropping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least a temporary answer for me is to do

```
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setSeconds(seconds => seconds + 1);
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);



// in return
      <header hidden className="App-header">
        {seconds} Woah.... You found me... I am the keeper of time. No one updates the time without me. If I am not here
        THE WORLD IS DOOMED!
      </header>
```